# Call destructor from empty define?

Tags: c++

Suppose the following header file:

```
#ifndef TEST_HEADER
#define TEST_HEADER 

class myFoo
{
    public:
    myFoo(unsigned long *ulbaz):
    baz(ulbaz)
    {
      *baz++;
    }
    ~myFoo()
    {
      *baz--;
    }
    private:
        unsigned long *baz;
    };

#define DEFINE_A( a ) myFoo bar( a);
#define DEFINE_B( b ) 

#endif  // test_header
```

code-example:

```
// code.cpp

#include "test.h"
unsigned long mylong = 0L;


int main()
{
    DEFINE_A( &mylong);
    DEFINE_B( &mylong);
}
```

As you can see, `DEFINE_B` is empty. What I don't understand: everytime `DEFINE_B` is called, I get into the destructor from `myFoo`, I can see that within the callstack - How can that be?
As far as I know an empty `define` expands to `;`.

Edit: This code now works.

Comment: Please create a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates this occurring ;)

Comment: Please show us the code which used these defines at least ...

Comment: Did you perhaps put the DEFINE_B() at the end of a scope in which you used DEFINE_A()?

Comment: Couldn't it just be that `bar` goes out of scope?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if it weren't a function... :)

Comment: Added a small code example

Comment: A macro without a body doesn't expand to a semicolon, it expands to nothing.

Comment: Your listing won't compile, since there is no `ulbaz` visible in the destructor. Please post a minimal self-contained test case that exhibits the problem.

Comment: What makes you think that `DEFINE_B` causes the destructor call?

Comment: @interjay Because I set a breakpoint there and watched the callstack

Comment: You can't see macros in the call stack.

Comment: @interjay correct, but i can see that this was the last line of code executed.

Comment: @fiscblog now your constructor doesn't use the value that is passed to it...

Comment: It's still broken (ditto @Hulk) - just copy+paste some _complete_ code you _actually compiled_, instead of trying to re-write it by hand.

Comment: It's the destructor, of course it's the last line of code executed. That has nothing to do with `DEFINE_B`. -1 to your question though for repeatedly posting code that you haven't tested.

Comment: @fiscblog: This has nothing to do with your macros.  The destructor is called when the variable goes out of scope at the end of the enclosing code block.

Comment: @NateChandler You mean it has nothin to do with `DEFINE_B`? Consider to write an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are running the following main:

```
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    unsigned long mylong = 0L;
    DEFINE_A( &mylong);
    DEFINE_B( &mylong);
    return 0;
}
```

The line `DEFINE_B( b )` expands to nothing, you see the destructor of the class `myFoo` because when the end of the scope is reached, all the objects that has been created inside them, are deleted by calling their destructors.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the object going out of the scope. Imagine the following example which will demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define EXAMPLEMACRO

class Test {
public:
    Test() {}
    ~Test() {}
}

int main() {

    //Open a new scope
    {
        EXAMPLEMACRO //This doesn't do anything!
        Test t();
        EXAMPLEMACRO //This called the destructor?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't call the destructor it is just your object going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
DEFINE_B( &mylong);
```

will turn into this  code. In other words, NOTHING will happen on that line at all.

Comment: Why is this downvoted, when exactly the same answer is approved as the correct answer? Bah!